How to extract Sentinel-2 RGB images at a custom spatial resolution (16m/pixel) when native band resolution is 10m?
I'm trying to extract a Sentinel-2 L2A dataset containing RGB images, in the span of some years, following this documentation: https://documentation.dataspace.copernicus.eu/notebook-samples/sentinelhub/introduction_to_SH_APIs.html#process-api
My specifications are as follows:

Spatial resolution: 16m/pixel
RGB channels

Since the main focus lies on these 2 parameters, the following lines of code are of interest:

Firstly the part where the bands and satellite are specified

def get_true_color_request(time_interval, bbox, size, config):

    evalscript_true_color = """
    //VERSION=3

    function setup() {
        return {
            input: [{
                bands: ["B02", "B03", "B04"]
            }],
            output: {
                bands: 3
            }
        };
    }

    function evaluatePixel(sample) {
        return [sample.B04, sample.B03, sample.B02];
    }
     """
    return SentinelHubRequest(
        evalscript=evalscript_true_color,
        input_data=[
            SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
                data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A.define_from(
                    "s2l2a", service_url=config.sh_base_url
                ),
                time_interval=time_interval,
                mosaicking_order=MosaickingOrder.LEAST_CC
            )
        ],
        responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.PNG)],
        bbox=bbox,
        size=size,
        config=config,
    )


Then, the part where the resolution is specified, for which the documentation writes: "Using the bbox_to_dimensions utility function, you can provide the desired resolution parameter of the image in meters and obtain the output image shape." And then provides the following lines of code:

resolution = 10
aoi_bbox = BBox(bbox=aoi_coords_wgs84, crs=CRS.WGS84)
aoi_size = bbox_to_dimensions(aoi_bbox, resolution=resolution)
print(f"Image shape at {resolution} m resolution: {aoi_size} pixels")

My problem lies mainly in this part of the code, because if I write resolution = 16, how will that be achieved? The bands I'll be using are B02, B03 & B04, which correspond to RGB, and for Sentinel-2A, the resolution for all 3 bands, is 10 m/pixel, as seen here.
Thing is, I actually did run the code, writing resolution = 16, and it did produce some images without any error popping up, but I’m unsure if they truly have a 16 m/pixel resolution.

how? by resampling the source data. did you expect something else? more detail on that? do the docs not say? if not, you'll have to dig into the source code.

@ChristophRackwitz The docs didn't mention resampling, as far as I saw. Thank you though for the answer! I assume the resampling is done on all bands, so if instead of 3 bands, I put 4 (adding B11 which has 20m/pixel), it will adjust all of them to 16.
